# How can add panel in navigation view ExtJs

Tags: extjs, extjs6-classic

How can I put panel with some text inside navigation view, like here http://joxi.ru/E2pyDJQC9MLnyA
I tried past panel in navigation `treelist` but panel not displayed.
Also I united my treelist and panel in joint container:

```
{
        xtype: 'maincontainerwrap',
        id: 'main-view-detail-wrap',
        reference: 'mainContainerWrap',
        flex: 1,
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'container',
                reference: 'leftContainer',
                itemId: 'leftContainer',
                layout: {
                    type: 'vbox',
                    align: 'stretch'
                },
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'treelist',
                        reference: 'navigationTreeList',
                        itemId: 'navigationTreeList',
                        ui: 'navigation',
                        store: 'NavigationTree',
                        width: 64,
                        micro: true,
                        expanderFirst: false,
                        expanderOnly: false,
                        listeners: {
                            itemclick: 'onNavigationItemClick',
                            selectionchange: 'onNavigationTreeSelectionChange'
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'panel',
                        header: false,
                        layout: 'fit',
                        height: 100,
                        hidden: checkSubscription().hidden,
                        width  : 64,
                        userCls: 'sidebar-purchase-wrapper',
                        renderTo: Ext.get("leftContainer"),
                        html   :
                        'My text Here'
                    },
            {
                xtype: 'container',
                flex: 1,
                reference: 'mainCardPanel',
                cls: 'sencha-dash-right-main-container',
                itemId: 'contentPanel',
                layout: {
                    type: 'card',
                    anchor: '100%'
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

Panel displayed, but when I'm click button onToggleNavigation animation not work correct.